# why the content loading time much after adding iptables rule?

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall, iptables

I added iptables rules in my Ubuntu PC and have taken few sites as whitelisted and remaining all are blocked. When I try to browse whitelisted site the content loading time takes very high and images, videos are not loading. What is the problem can you suggest me.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Allow loopback

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

## client: ==
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#facebook
iptables -A OUTPUT -d facebook.com -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d facebook.com -j ACCEPT

#youtube 
iptables -A OUTPUT -d youtube.com -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d youtube.com -j ACCEPT

#stackoverflow
iptables -A OUTPUT -d stackoverflow.com -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d stackoverflow.com -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

All the media content of those websites is not hosted on the same top-level domain, but on many subdomains, secondary domains, and CDNs. For example, you need to whitelist `graph.facebook.com` (which is not the same as `facebook.com`!) to actually see content on your fb feed. Youtube loads videos from `*.googlevideo.com`, images from `*.ytimg.com` and so on. There's far more stuff, but to put it simply, iptables is not the right tool for this job.

Simply put, you're actually blocking far more than you think, and whitelisting websites through iptables is far too simplistic for general web usage - especially when dealing with massive websites like Youtube, Facebook, and many others.

To get a better picture of all the connections that are happening in the background, I would suggest trying the uMatrix extension for your browser: it gives you a pretty good insight of all the connections that websites are trying to make, and even allows you to control which ones to allow, which ones to block, and much more.

Alternatively, you might want to set up your own [Pi-Hole DNS server](https://pi-hole.net/) and go from there.
This probably the best approach in your case.